# Wrong result when evaluating multi-line boolean statement in Ansible yaml file

Tags: ansible, yaml

Using ansible 2.7.5 I am trying to create a multi-line boolean parameter.

I first verified that it works as expected as one-line with:

```
FOOD: apple
IS_FRUIT: '{% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false{% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true{% endif %}'
```

and then a task:

```
- name: "FOOD is: {{ FOOD }}" 
  debug: msg="FOOD is {{ FOOD }} where IS_FRUIT {{ IS_FRUIT | bool }}"
```

which prints:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "FOOD is apple where IS_FRUIT [ True ]"
}
```

as expected when run.

Based on:

[In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines)

I have then tried:

```
IS_FRUIT: >-
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false
 {% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true
 {% endif %}
```

but that prints:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "FOOD is apple where IS_FRUIT [ False ]"
}
```

which is wrong. I found this post describing a similar issue:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18142

but it does not really provide a solution. Any suggestion on how to create multi-line boolean variables in Ansible?

Based on below answer I have also tried:

```
FOOD: apple

IS_FRUIT: |
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false
 {% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true
 {% endif %}
```

but when I run that with the same task above I still get:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "FOOD is apple where IS_FRUIT False"
}
```

which is wrong.

Comment: Not sure if relevant but you should drop the surrounding `'`s in the `>-` version since they would become part of the content.

Comment: For the simpler case - just adding one new line - that fixed the error. But for multiple lines - see above updated example it still fails.

Answer (score 5):

*Boring explanation about what happens*

```
IS_FRUIT: >-
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false
 {% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true
 {% endif %}
```

Mind that in YAML, a *folded block scalar* (starting with `>`) replaces single newlines with spaces (and multiple newlines with one fewer newline). So the code above is equivalent to

```
IS_FRUIT: >-
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false {% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true {% endif %}
```

So after Jinja processing, you will get either `false` or `true` *with a trailing space*. YAML will not map those scalars to boolean values because of that trailing space.

Now I *guess* that Ansible sees it gets a non-boolean value, and it maps that non-boolean value to a boolean one in some way. And thus your scalar evaluates to `False` even if it is `true` with trailing space (markdown does not let me render this correctly).

---

*Important part about how to fix it*

You can use a *literal block scalar* instead (based on **clockworknet**'s suggestion):

```
IS_FRUIT: |-
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false
 {% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true
 {% endif %}
```

This works because now the newlines will not be transformed into spaces, but stay newlines instead. After Jinja processing, only one line remains, and the final newline character will get stripped away by the `-` in `|-`.

However, this does not help you if you have more complex expressions where you want to actually split the content over multiple lines. There is a better solution which is [Jinja whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control):

```
IS_FRUIT: >-
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false
 {%- elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true
 {%- endif %}
```

The `-` on the Jinja tags tells Jinja to remove *all* whitespace before this tag, so this is basically equivalent to

```
IS_FRUIT: >-
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false{% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true{% endif %}
```

You can also use it like this `-%}` to remove all whitespace *after* a tag. However, beware: Jinja processing takes place before YAML processing, so it may screw up your carefully written YAML indentation! For example, do not use `{%-` on the first Jinja tag in the block scalar, for Jinja would then place the text on the same line as `|-` which is invalid YAML! Same goes for the last tag and `-%}`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice explanation of what's going on by @flyx.

I'd recommend to avoid using Jinja *statements* in your playbooks in favour of Jinja *expressions*.
Still statements are OK inside file templates.

You can write your vars definition as follows:

```
IS_FRUIT: >-
  {{ false if FOOD == 'carrot'
     else
     (
       true if FOOD in ['apple', 'banana']
       else 'unknown'
     )
  }}
```

In this case we do care only about last newline which is stripped away with `>-`.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
IS_FRUIT: |
 {% if FOOD == "carrot" %}false
 {% elif FOOD == "apple" or FOOD == "banana" %}true
 {% endif %}
```

(change to the `|` symbol to use literal multiline behaviour)

Comment: I have also tried - see updated post - but same wrong result.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Misread the subtlety of the question. You have an excellent answer from @flyx so hopefully your problem is resolved.